# Issue tracker for Github itself?

Tags: github

I found a SVG-related problem with Github itself and would like to report it but can't find any issue tracker for the Github platform.

Is there such an issue tracker or how can I report a problem with github.com?

Comment: send them an email. They have many people working on this kind of stuff.

Comment: Off topic because you don't want to use their contact form and it's not a programming issue you have

Comment: In my opinion, a bug or annoyance on the GitHub website can very well be a programming issue. Most programmers use that website every day. It is a programming tool, dedicated to catching bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact them via https://github.com/contact and describe the issue. GitHub doesn’t have any public issue tracker.